# Geofencing using Google glass

Tags: google-maps, google-glass, google-gdk, android-geofence

I am trying to port the Android [Geofence app](http://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html) to Google glass. I wanted to know if Glass supports methods provided natively by Android's `LocationProvider` . More importantly, can Glass recognize and communicate with Google Play services.

Is there a demo map explaining maps in Glass?

Comment: I haven't tired to do anything with maps myself, but a couple of things to bare in mind: there is an [issue around play services](https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/detail?id=176&q=component=GDK&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Owner%20Component%20Summary) and the device doesn't have GPS on board, and regular navigation only works when paired with a phone.  I'd be interested to know how you get on with this.

Comment: Google PlayServices is not available yet on Google Glass.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that without Play Services with [LocationManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html) and using [addProximityAlert](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#addProximityAlert%28double,%20double,%20float,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29) which sets a proximity alert for the location given by the position (latitude, longitude) and the given radius.